# grafana-server failed at CHDIR step

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, influxdb, grafana

I installed `grafana` on my `ubuntu 16.04` machine as it said in its [official documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/install/); then I have performed enabling:

```
zeinab@ZiZi:~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
zeinab@ZiZi:~$ sudo systemctl stop grafana-server
zeinab@ZiZi:~$ sudo systemctl start grafana-server
zeinab@ZiZi:~$ sudo systemctl enable grafana-server
```

But `sudo netstat -plntua | grep 3000` returns nothing. I've made no changes in configurations. nothing is written in `/var/log/grafana/grafana.log`, but during above commands' execution, I get following lines on `/var/log/syslog` for `grafana`:

```
Feb 15 15:11:38 ZiZi systemd[1]: Stopped Starts and stops a single grafana instance on this system.
Feb 15 15:11:44 ZiZi systemd[1902]: grafana-server.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/sbin/grafana-server: No such file or directory
Feb 15 15:11:44 ZiZi systemd[1]: Started Starts and stops a single grafana instance on this system.
Feb 15 15:11:44 ZiZi systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Feb 15 15:11:44 ZiZi systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 15 15:11:44 ZiZi systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What's the cause? Did I do something wrong? Is it related to the installation process?

**EDIT 1:**

Following is what `sudo systemctl status grafana-server` returns:

```
● grafana-server.service - Starts and stops a single grafana instance on this system
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-02-15 15:11:44 +0330; 8min ago
     Docs: http://docs.grafana.org
 Main PID: 1902 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Feb 15 15:11:44 ZiZi systemd[1]: Started Starts and stops a single grafana instance on this system.
Feb 15 15:11:44 ZiZi systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Feb 15 15:11:44 ZiZi systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 15 15:11:44 ZiZi systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the stable version and edition for downloading grafana at
https://grafana.com/grafana/download/9.1.6?edition=oss
Remove the previously installed grafana version and download it from the above link, it works!!!

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining _why_ it works and why the asker's approach doesn't work.